# Can \$I_E = I_B\$ in a BJT?

Tags: bjt

[image]So I have been trying to solve this BJT problem for the last 20 min with no luck so far.

My question is, in this circuit, is \$I_B = I_E\$?

I have tried solving the problem with this consideration and without, but still can't do it.

Btw, the hint basically gives us \$V_{BE} = 0.8 \$ and \$V_{CE} = 0.2\$

EDIT:

I have tried solving it using KVL: 
$$5 - 2{I_B} - V_{BE} - 3{I_E} = 0$$

That got me no where. I then thought \$I_B\$ may be equal to \$I_E\$ but the answer I got was wrong.

Comment: Ib = Ie only if the collector is disconnected. How have you tried solving it?

Comment: Welcome to the site. As said, Ib = Ie only if there's no collector current. Knowing that, edit your question and add your workings so far (**no photos of hardwritten notes**, please). The better the quality of your question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract.

Comment: @TonyM Hi! I have added an edit on what I tried to do. Thanks for sharing the info!

Comment: @DKNguyen Hi! I have tried using KVL. I added and edit to my post. Thanks!

Comment: @RayanAlHobayb That's just one loop equation, but you have two loops. (the vertical traces are also a loop). Current flows from Vcc through 7k, through C-E, through the 3K and back to Vcc again.

Comment: @DKNguyen Yes! That is correct. For some reason I always fail to seem these vertical loops... Thanks!

Comment: @Jasen  no , Ie=Ib only if collector is open circuit  then you just have a diode for Vbe, Ib=Ie  then Vcb=0 thus Vc=Ve

Comment: If Ve= approx 3/(3+7) 12V= 4V and Vbe=0.6 and Ib= 0.4V/2k = 200 uA and Ie= 4V/3k=1.33mA  so Ic = 1.33-200uA = 1.13mA so \$\beta = 1.13/0.2=5.65\$  so b) is closest answer

Comment: Are you sure the hint gives 0.2V and 0.8V, because these values do not give any of the answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is, in this circuit, is \$I_B = I_E\$?

No, \$I_E = I_C + I_B\$ and \$I_C\$ is clearly not zero.

As for solving it:

$$2000 * I_B + 0.8 + 3000 * I_E = 5$$

$$7000 * I_C + 0.2 + 3000 * I_E = 12$$

You now have 3 equations and 3 unknowns so you should be able to solve this easily enough.

Answer (score 1):

If Vce is saturated then the 12 volts is mostly across 7k+3k with 11.9V/10k=1.19mA

**Vce when saturated at this low current may be < 0.1V**

so Ve= approx 3/(3+7) 12V(= 3.6V)+Ib*Re ~ 4V

**and Vbe=0.6 when Ic ~ 1mA**  (not 0.7 as suggested)

and V(Rb=2k) =5V-Vbe-Ve = 5V-0.6V-4V=0.4V
so Ib= 0.4V/2k  = 200 uA

and Ie= 4V/3k=1.33mA
so Ic = 1.33-200uA = 1.13mA

so \$Ic/Ib = 1.13/0.2=5.65\$

so b) 6.07 is the closest answer

Trust but verify !!

[image]

Calculations verified  and Assumptions in **bold**